# set categorical feature for x tick and y tick in scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, scatter-plot

I have written the code as follows to plot a scatter plot. It appears to be correct, but I would like to set the x-axis tick labels and y-axis tick labels as categorical values using the column1_feature and column2_feature columns. However, the code does not seem to consider these columns as categorical features and instead uses numerical values from column1 and column2. Could someone please help me understand where the problem might be?

```
def plot_cross_tabulation_scatter(data, column1, column2, selected_year1, selected_year2):
    if selected_fmpyear1 < 0:
        filtered_df1 = data[data["YEAR_x"] == selected_year1]
    else:
        filtered_df1 = data[data["YEAR_x"] == abs(selected_year1)]
    if selected_fmpyear2 < 0:
        filtered_df2 = data[data["YEAR_x"] == selected_year2]
    else:
        filtered_df2 = data[data["YEAR_x"] == abs(selected_year2)]

    df_filtered = data[
        (data["YEAR_x"] == selected_year1)
        | (data["YEAR_x"] == selected_year2)
    ]

    x_values = df_filtered[column1].astype(float).values
    y_values = df_filtered[column2].astype(float).values

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    x_spread = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, len(x_values))
    y_spread = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, len(y_values))

    ax.scatter(x_values , y_values , s=3, alpha=0.3)

    # Set categorical labels on x-axis tick labels if column1_feature exists
    if f"{column1}_FEATURE" in df_filtered.columns:
        x_categories = df_filtered[f"{column1}_FEATURE"].unique()
        x_categories_labels = [str(category) for category in x_categories]
        ax.set_xticks(range(len(x_categories)))
        ax.set_xticklabels(x_categories_labels, rotation=45, fontsize=7)

    # Set categorical labels on y-axis tick labels if column2_feature exists
    if f"{column2}_FEATURE" in df_filtered.columns:
        y_categories = df_filtered[f"{column2}_FEATURE"].unique()
        y_categories_labels = [str(category) for category in y_categories]
        ax.set_yticks(range(len(y_categories)))
        ax.set_yticklabels(y_categories_labels, fontsize=7)

    ax.set_xlabel(f"{column1} at YEAR{selected_fmpyear1}")
    ax.set_ylabel(f"{column2} at YEAR{selected_fmpyear2}")
    ax.set_title(f"Scatter Plot of {column1} vs. {column2}")

    plt.show()
    st.pyplot(fig)

    return fig
```